# Run this script just as OTRS user! Or use 'Cron.sh {start|stop|restart} OTRS_USER' as root

Tags: cron, otrs

I installed OTRS 4.0.5, while login as root@localhot it gives notification as Scheduler is not running -> red color ribbon below menu item in home page.

While clicking the notification it gives follow the three steps

1. Make sure that /opt/otrs/var/cron/scheduler_watchdog exists (without .dist extension) -- **exist**
2. Check that cron deamon is running in the system-- **Checked**
   with this **command** *ps -ef | grep crond*

   **Output as**
   root      1589     1  0 Apr16 ?        00:00:02 crond 
   root     29843 29780  0 10:37 pts/1    00:00:00 grep crond

3.Confirm that OTRS cron jobs are running, execute /opt/otrs/bin/Cron.sh start

I stuck in the step 3: kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by "stuck" you mean you get the error message given in the subject.

Just follow the text, literally:

Either become the user "otrs" and then call

   `/opt/otrs/bin/Cron.sh restart`

Or work as "root" and call

   `/opt/otrs/bin/Cron.sh restart otrs`

Both are based on the assumption that you installed the OTRS software for the user "otrs". If not, you have to adapt that user name.

Comment: And @Jorg can you help me to get out from this also "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229589/how-to-link-the-ticket-types-with-the-respective-queue-in-otrs"  i posted the question check and help me